# Protocol extension and generics in Swift 3. Is this even possible?

Tags: design-patterns, swift3

I'm reading [Head First Design Patterns](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-Design-Patterns-Freeman/dp/0596007124/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1485905094&sr=1-1&keywords=head%20first%20design%20patterns) and I'm trying to replicate the Design Patterns in a Swift Playground. I'm trying to get the Observer pattern working as per the book.
My current source is as follows:

```
protocol Subject {
    func register(observer: Observer)
    func remove(observer: Observer)
    func notifyObservers()
}

protocol Observer {
    func update(temperature: Double, humidity: Double, pressure: Double)
}

protocol DisplayElement {
    func display()
}

class WeatherData: Subject {
    
    var observers: [Observer]
    
    var temperature: Double!
    var humidity: Double!
    var pressure: Double!
    
    init() {
        observers = []
    }
    
    func register(observer: Observer) {
        observers.append(observer)
    }
    
    func remove(observer: Observer) {
    
    }
    
    func notifyObservers() {
        for obs: Observer in observers {
            obs.update(temperature: temperature, humidity: humidity, pressure: pressure)
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to implement the removeObserver method. The snippet that I need to implement is something as:

```
func remove(observer: Observer) {
    let obs: Observer = observers.index(where: { (aObserver) -> Bool in
        return aObserver == observer
    })
}
```

However this is not allowing me to continue because of a compilation error:

### Cannot convert value of type '(*OptionalNilComparisonType) -> Bool' to expected argument type '(*) -> Bool'

Is it even possible to achieve this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `if let observerIndex = observers.index(where: { $0 ==  observer }) {  // use observerIndex here }`

Comment: I get the same error with the if let syntax

Comment: Your protocol Observer doesn't conform to Equatable

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried conforming to the Equatable protocol, but I get several of these errors: **"Protocol 'Observer' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"**. Also I do not want the Observer to be a struct, because I would like each object to be able to become an Observer without extending, but with conforming.

Comment: Couldn't make it work. Got several different errors. Seems I cannot redefine the == operator in a protocol with default behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arbitrary objects are can not be tested for equality. There are many kinds of objects which full equality is difficult or even impossible to determine in Swift (and generally speaking in most popular languages; Swift just addresses this problem more explicitly than many other languages do). There are [lots of ways to address this](https://gist.github.com/rnapier/58e00f3c3260950be0dc), but in your case you really likely mean that the observer is some specific instance of a class, a reference type, rather than a value. The number 4 is probably not allowed to be an observer, for instance. That's something that can happen in Swift, so you need to tell Swift that it isn't legal here because 4 is a value, not a reference.

OK, enough background. How do you do it? Well, first, say Observers have to be classes (i.e. reference types).

```
protocol Observer: class {
```

And now, you can say "if this object is *exactly the same object* as the observer" which is completely different than "if this thing is equal to the observer:"

```
func remove(observer: Observer) {
    if let index = observers.index(where: { (aObserver) -> Bool in
        return aObserver === observer
    }) {
        observers.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Note the use of `===` here rather then `==`.

There are lots of other ways to attack this general problem, but this is the way that best matches the Observer pattern.